# Spring data create index dynamiclly reference to the entity field

Tags: java, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to annotate my entity with @Document.

Are there any why to create Index dynamiclly reference to the field  **lastTime**?

for example: **lastTime** = "2022-03-8 00:00:00"

Index should be created as **aaa-2022-03-08**.

How should I set the **indexName** in **@Doucument**?

```java
@Data
@Document(indexName = "xth_alert-#{}")
public class EsAlert {

  
    @Nullable
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    public Date lastTime;
}
```

thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, please consider to type the exact requirement is question title as well to get the most of it, also if the answers satisfy your requirement please consider to accept and approve them as answer, otherwise feel free to comment.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer :

Yes, you can ingest entities to store on indexes with SpEL template expression like

`"log-#{T(java.time.LocalDate).now().toString()}"`

And if you lastTime field is generated by local time the result will be like this,

```html
@Data
@Document(indexName = "log-#{T(java.time.LocalDate).now().toString()}")
public class EsAlert {

  
    @Nullable
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    public Date lastTime;
}
```

Comment: Emm, I want to create index according to the lastTime field ,not now. Are there any ways to get lastTime by SpEL in the @Doucument annotation?